# Firebase cloud messages não envia mensagens pra todos os dispositivos que usam o app

Tags: firebase, push-notification, flutter

eu implementei o cloud messaging do Firebase usando flutter e até aí tudo bem, testei o envio de notificações push pra um emulador de um android e funcionou tudo bem, a notificação chegou no meu emulador, no entanto, gerei um APK da minha aplicação e testei novamente, fiz o envio da notificação push pelo Firebase e não funcionou, só enviou pro meu emulador, alguém já teve problema parecido? Meu celular tá no Android 9, já o emulador no Android 6.

O emulador eu já testei na notificação anteriormente

Comment: não entendi pq a pergunta foi fechada antes de ser feito *ao menos UM comentário* sugerindo uma melhoria.

Comment: provavelmente você está usando o `fcm_token` para enviar suas notificações/mensagens. Cada aparelho acaba tendo um `fcm_token` diferente, então seguindo esse método você precisa enviar 3 notificações uma para cada token (não me lembro se é possível enviar uma notificação para 3 tokens). Sugestão: USE TÓPICOS. Crie um tópico com um código único desse usuário, em seu app dê um `subscribeToTopic` nesse tópico e envie a notificação para este tópico. Os 3 devices receberão a notificação.